# Converting Aster L1T data radiance to surface reflectance in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, aster

I'm working with Aster data in GEE and it's necessary to convert radiance in surface Reflectance values. I've tried to convert DN to TOA values, like this. It works. But I'm a little confused about convert TOA values to BOA values. I know that it's necessary to apply the atmospheric correction. I've looked around for the best model for ASTER data in GEE, but I didn't find a good solution yet

```
var aster1 = ee.Image('ASTER/AST_L1T_003/20000507134140');
var gainRED = aster1.get('GAIN_COEFFICIENT_B02');
print(gainRED);
var rad_RED = ee.Image('ASTER/AST_L1T_003/20000507134140')
                  .select('B02')
                  .subtract(1)
                  .multiply(0.708);
print(rad_RED);
Map.addLayer(rad_RED);
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to contain a problem statement.  Yes, the code is required, but so is a description of what it actually does (instead of what you wanted).

Comment: What happened when you ran the code that you have presented?

Comment: It works. But I'm a little confused about convert TOA values to BOA values. I know that it's necessary to apply the atmospheric correction. I've looked around for the best model for ASTER data in GEE, but I didn't find a good solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to atmospheric correction, you need a Atmospheric radiative transfer, such as MORTRAN,6S.
Second, the Model runs in your computer. So if you want to use the GEE, you have to use the Python API.
You can refer this.
https://github.com/samsammurphy/gee-atmcorr-S2/blob/master/jupyer_notebooks/sentinel2_atmospheric_correction.ipynb